# DAE or STL with textures behaves strange in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2, sdf, stl, dae

I have "landscape" 3d shape, either STL or DAE (no texture or UV mapping in this DAE).
I am trying to show it in Gazebo and to "stretch" a png texture on it.
Now, first of all, this approach works just fine if instead of 3d mesh I use simple shape, like cube.
But with mesh...
For STL I have ONE color over the shape, it seems that the scale is horribly wrong.
In DAE, no mater what I do with flags in material file, it shows tiles images, while I want a single one.
Here is my setup:

```
src/models
├── perfect_topo.dae
├── perfect_topo.stl
├── topo_maps
│   ├── materials
│   │   └── scripts
│   │       └── perfect.material
│   └── textures
│       └── perfect.png
```

src/worlds
perfect.sdf

World (fragment):

```
<sdf version='1.7'>
    <world name='default'>
        <model name="landscape">
            <static>true</static>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>

            <link name="link">
                <pose>-100 -100 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <visual name="visual">
                    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                    <geometry>
                        <mesh>
                            <uri>../models/perfect_topo.dae</uri>
                            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
                        </mesh>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <script>
                            <uri>file://src/models/topo_maps/materials/scripts</uri>
                            <uri>file://src/models/topo_maps/textures/perfect.png</uri>
                            <name>perfect</name>
                        </script>
                    </material>
                 
                </visual>

                <collision name="collision">
                    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                    <geometry>
                        <mesh>
                            <uri>../models/perfect_topo.dae</uri>
                            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
                        </mesh>
                    </geometry>
                    <surface>
                        <contact>
                            <collide_bitmask>65535</collide_bitmask>
                            <ode/>
                        </contact>
                        <friction>
                            <ode>
                                <mu>100</mu>
                                <mu2>50</mu2>
                            </ode>
                            <torsional>
                                <ode/>
                            </torsional>
                        </friction>
                        <bounce/>
                    </surface>
                    <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
                </collision>            
            </link>
        </model>
```

perfect.material

```
material perfect
{
  technique
  {
    pass
    {
      texture_unit
      {
        texture perfect.png
        scale 1 1
        //padding 0.5
        
        u_repeat 1
        v_repeat 1
        //filter trilinear
        //max_anisotropy 8
        
        repeat_u false
        repeat_v false     
        wrap clamp
        wrap_s clamp
        wrap_t clamp
        
        //filtering anisotropic
        //max_anisotropy 8
        //scale 1 1
        // set wrap to "clamp" to prevent tiling
        wrap s_clamp t_clamp        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how to show ONE image on upper side of the 3d shape (and not around it, as there is no point in showing map on the side of landscape that faces down.

Or to start with, at least to turn off tiling.

Here is what I see so far:
[image: tiled image]

Comment: The problem is solved: see my other question at
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105771/unable-to-use-uv-mapping-of-dae-file-in-gazebo-simulator/105820#105820